# Rename parents with powershell

Tags: powershell, rename

I have C:\test1\test2\test3\test4\test5\test6\test7\test8

I need to rename each folder of a path starting from the last one (test8) to the first(test1). I have to test on Windows 10 folders with a max lenght name and to do so I need to change first the name of the last folder (test8) and then its parent (test7).

I have this function

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [string]$path
)


function createFolderStructure{

        $parentName = "F:\"
        $name = "ThisFolderHas256Characters_ThisFolderHas256Characters_"+
                "ThisFolderHas256Characters_ThisFolderHas256Characters_"+
                "ThisFolderHas256Characters_ThisFolderHas256Characters_"+
                "ThisFolderHas256Characters_ThisFolderHas256Characters_"+
                "ThisFolderHas256Characters_ThisFolderHas"

        for ($i=0; $i -lt 10; $i++){
            $parentName += "test\";
            New-Item "$parentName" -ItemType Directory;
        }

        Get-ChildItem -Path "F:\test" -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object{
                Rename-Item -Path $_.fullname -NewName $name
            }
     }



createFolderStructure
```

But I have no idea how to make it go from bottom to top element. As I have it, it doesnt work, since it goes from the first folder to the last, and on the second folder I get the exception of name too long for a path. Any idea??

Comment: Have you tried to enable NTFS long paths, so you can exceed the 260 chars max path length?

Comment: How do you make it past the first one? You should get an error on the first folder you try to rename regardless of if it is "C:\test1" or "C:\test1\test2\test3\test4\test5\test6\test7\test8"

Comment: Is your end goal to make a full folder path with a length of 2572? On the F: drive with 10 folders nested in each other, each folder having a 256 character name?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this recursively with a function. I think you may need to shorten the $name variable though:

```
Function Rename-Folders {
param([string]$path)

$name = "ThisFolderHas256Characters_ThisFolderHas256Characters_"+
                "ThisFolderHas256Characters_ThisFolderHas256Characters_"+
                "ThisFolderHas256Characters_ThisFolderHas256Characters_"+
                "ThisFolderHas256Characters_ThisFolderHas256Characters_"+
                "ThisFolderHas256Characters_ThisFolderHas"

if ($path -match "$($path | split-path -qualifier)\\?$") {
return
}
Get-Item -path $path | Rename-Item -NewName $name
Rename-Folders -path ($path | split-path)
}

$path = "F:\test1\test2\test3\test4"
Rename-Folders $path
```

Answer (score -1):

First off, as you noted, there are character restrictions. Total path length cannot be over 256 characters for any file in the last directory, and directory length cannot be more than 248 characters. You'll want to throw in some checks for that. Up front this means that your 256 character folder name should never work. Ever.

If you know what the full path is, and just want to work your way up the directory structure to a root folder you can use the `.Parent` property for the folder object.

The below is really just a proof of concept that will create a folder structure, with a file nested in it, and then given a starting and end point will work from the deepest nested folder specified to the target folder, renaming folders as it goes until it hits a length limitation.

```
$NewName = 'ReallyExtremelyLongFolderName'
Remove-Item C:\Test -Recurse -Force -ea 0
Remove-Item "C:\$NewName" -Recurse -Force -ea 0

$RootFolder = "C:\test"
$TargetFolder = 'C:\test\Test\Test\Test\Test\Test\Test\Test\test'
New-Item "C:\test\Test\Test\Test\Test\Test\Test\Test\test\Test\Some Long File.xlsx" -force |Out-Null
$LongestFileName = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -recurse | Sort {$_.FullName.Length} | Select -last 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
$MaxLength = If((Get-Item $LongestFileName).PSIsContainer){248}Else{256}
$CurrentFolder = Get-Item $TargetFolder
$NewTarget = $TargetFolder
$VerbosePreference='Continue'
Do{
    Write-Verbose "Working on:                $($CurrentFolder.FullName)"
    $NewTargetTmp = $NewTarget.Replace($CurrentFolder.FullName,(Join-Path (split-path $CurrentFolder.FullName) $NewName))
    #Check new path for existing longest path
    Write-Verbose "Checking new longest path: $($LongestFileName.Replace($NewTarget,$NewTargetTmp))`nLength: $($LongestFileName.Replace($NewTarget,$NewTargetTmp).length)`n"
    If(($LongestFileName=$LongestFileName.Replace($NewTarget,$NewTargetTmp)).Length -gt $MaxLength) {Write-Warning "New target path to deepest nested file/folder too long:`n$LongestFileName";break}
    $CurrentFolder | Rename-Item -NewName $NewName
    $NewTarget = $NewTargetTmp
    $CurrentFolder = Get-Item $CurrentFolder.Parent.FullName
}Until($CurrentFolder.FullName -eq $RootFolder)
$VerbosePreference='SilentlyContinue'
```

You can comment out the `$VerbosePreference` lines (there's 2 of them) to make this less spammy.